# What does the highlighted sentence mean in the paragraph given down below? I couldn't make the sense out of it

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What does the highlighted sentence mean?

**So what should one conclude about America’s own proximity to Trump’s global latrine now that “places like Norway” have decided to keep their borders indefinitely closed to us?**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "latrine" is a reference back to "shithole" and means the same thing. (I'm assuming you've looked up the words.) The article says that Trump rejected immigrants from countries that he said were "shitholes", that is, "latrines".

He did this while saying that he would prefer immigrants from Europe, like those from Norway.

It happens now that European countries, including Norway, have forbidden travelers from the United States because of its failure to control the COVID-19 epidemic.

The author asks rhetorically, how close the US is to being a latrine (shithole) country in the eyes of the Europeans.